# Is eye-tracking feasible?

Tags: google-cardboard

Food for thought: since most smartphones have selfie cameras, is eye-tracking and blink-tracking feasible, considering that most of the light is from the screen? I understand that Android already does a crude version of this to set the orientation and to keep the display awake.

Comment: I don't think this post comes to programming.

Answer (score 1):

Eye tracking using the hone camera is not feasible.

For one, check out where the camera is placed on your phone - in most headsets it wont see the users eyes at all. if the camera even was to see an eye, it would see only one eye. Then there are the lenses distorting the image. Also, proper eye tracking requires at least two cameras and needs to be properly calibrated... Long story short - eye tracking is not trivial, and certainly cannot be used as you describe with current phone design.

And no, Android does not use eye tracking for orientation. It uses the accelerometer for that. For hiding the display when talking, it uses an illumination sensor - there is little light between the sensor and your skull when you hold the phone to your ear.